# Move 4.5gb file from local windows 7 pc to windows server 2008

Tags: windows-7, windows-server-2008

Does anyone know any tricks to move over a 4.5 gb file from local pc to virtual server?? I am working on the last hairs of my head, and I would like to keep them.

Comment: scp? cifs? smb? bittorent? irc dcc? what have you tried? Why haven't they worked?

Comment: A local virtual server, or a remote one? On a machine you have physical access to (if so, how far away? What's the bandwidth between them?)  As long as the link is ~100KB/s, you might as well scp it, it's unlikely you'll get a better answer before it's done.

Comment: Whichever approach I started with, I would ensure it had resume support :)

Comment: HOW DO I USE SCP?

Answer (score 1):

a) Map the virtual server as a network drive (like: \\192.168.0.1\C$) in Windows Explorer, and do a standard copy.

b) I usually manage my virtual hosts via Remote Desktop, if you're using the recent remote desktop client, you can Ctrl+C -> Ctrl+V any files and easily copy from one location to another. (Warning, it may lock your desktop with a sticky copy dialog).

Answer (score 1):

c) some of them also supports drag'n'drop.
d) samba
e) ftp server
f) http server

in case the machine and virtual server are in other subnets use port forwarding